# Performance with datetime search on many records

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, date, datetime

I have an application that is very depended on date. It stores thousands of records per day and almost every query needs to check the date field to make sure it matches the search date. But as the application grows, the performance is dropping. Changing the application to enhance performance is required, but will take a lot of time. So before I start, I was hoping to get some insight in how to change it for best results.

Currently the date is stored in a `datetime` column (with index). In some case the time is required (EG: You'll be picked up at 2014-10-02 10:24) and in some case it is not (EG: I need daily transportation from 2014-10-01 till 2014-10-30). The first thing I want to do is split the date and time fields, so when searching for date I don't have to worry about the time.

The get the records for a specific date they've used `DATEDIFF(D, DateTime, GetDate())=0`, but that doesn't use the index (full scan). To solve I could use `Datum=DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GetDate()))` which uses the index and thus is quicker.

But I was wondering, would it be even quicker to split the date in three separate columns (year, month, day) and skip date functions completely? Or is there another way to speed things up significantly?

**Example/reason splitting:**

```
Table members: Id, MemberId, Datetime, CarId
Table car: Id, Name
```

I need a list of all cars that drive today. So:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Car
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT CarId
  FROM Members
  WHERE DATEDIFF(D, DateTime, GetDate())=0
)
```

Now if the datetime would be seperated, I could use (to use index)

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Car
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT CarId
  FROM Members
  WHERE Date=DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GetDate()))
)
```

Now I want to show all the members for a specific car/date in order.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM Members
  WHERE Date=DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GetDate()))
  AND CarId=1
  ORDER BY Time -- new split col
```

But perhaps its even faster to split it up some more to use

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Car
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT CarId
  FROM Members
  WHERE Year=2014
  AND Month=10
  AND Day=2
)
```

Comment: I suspect splitting date and time may actually lower performance. Could you add a sample query where you think it would help so that we can understand the motivation better or possibly come up with an alternate approach?

Comment: Well from first shot it doesn't seems problem, but can you provide data structure of table and complete query. Also, how many records you have?

Comment: Updated question. About 100.000 records will be added per month to some tables, so performance will go down fast if it's not altered properly

Comment: What happens when you run the subquery over the members table by itself? Performance could also take a massive hit if there is no index on the `CarId` field.

Comment: One trick I often use and works fine for me, don't know techincal explanation is I use date as '2014-10-01 00:00:01' to time 23:59:59. with between. This trigger proper index without any calculation on either part. But maybe you should run a background task that find summary and store in some summary table if you are really going to get 100,000 records per month.

Comment: @md4 That would only affect the third query, but it is the date that is causing the problems

Comment: @SumitGupta Thanks, I have tried the between version and it does use the index, but it is still slower then a split date time. (40% for split date and 60% for between in test batch according to the execution plan)

Comment: I have 2M record in my table that works fine for me, split date is not adviced as it take more storage [including the indexes] and ultimately somewhere it slow down maybe overtime. Rather you should split this members table per year basis. So, it never cross say 1M record, you can make it 2 yr split but don't go too long this will keep your records in check.

Comment: How about to store date as number?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355381/sql-server-datetime-vs-int-key-performance

Answer (score 0):

I've provided some optimised sql below, but more information would be useful. Also the ddl of you table and indexs would be useful to provide insight.

1) list of cars that drive today

```
select c.id, c.name
from members as m
inner join car as c
on c.Id = m.CarId
where 
    m.datetime < '2014-10-04 00:00:00'
    and m.datetime >= '2014-10-03 00:00:00'

-- you could pipe that date calculation into the genated sql
-- or work with the getDate function and use ceiling 

where 
    m.datetime < DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT (date, GETDATE())) --tomorrow
    and m.datetime >= CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) --today
```

Currently your code doed a calculation for ever single row and there is potential for poor performance on search arguments (sargs)

2) list all members for a specific car and date in order:

```
select m.*
from members as m
where 
    m.carId = 1
    and m.datetime < '2014-10-04 00:00:00'
    and m.datetime >= '2014-10-03 00:00:00'
order by m.datetime
```

Notes:

I) datetimes being split up and then have restrictions on them filtering is not advisable

II) fast growth of tables - it may be worth while partitioning table on date, or 
moving older data to a historical table so you're only dealing with a smaller data set.

III) it maybe worth setting up a trigger on insert to create an additional column called date 
that you could then query against if you have restrictions on how you application querys against it.

Additional information requested:

I) can you provide the DDL off tables and indexing?

II) current row count and count distinct on carid/id/memberid